# Deduct leave balance from annual leave

Tags: php, yii2

How can I deduct the Leave Balance when someone has applied the leave?

This is from `Leaveapplication.php`. As you can see, there is a "Leave Taken" column:

[image]

And this is from `Annualleave.php`:

[image]

I want to deduct "Leave Taken" from the "Leave Balance" column every time a user applies the leave.

I have tried this code:

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Leaveapplication();
    $model1 = new Annualleave();
    //$defaultstatus = $model->leave_application_status_id == '1';
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {

        /*Yii::$app->mailer->compose()
        ->setFrom('nazmigol@gmail.com')
        ->setTo('nazmiscore@gmail.com')
        ->setSubject('Leave Application')
        ->setTextBody('nak cuti boss')
        ->setHTMLBody('Cuti lah bosskuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu')
        ->send();*/

        $leavetype = $model->leaveType_id;
        $date1 = $model->startDate;
        $date2 = $model->endDate;

        $date1 = strtotime($date1);
        $date2 = strtotime($date2);

       switch($leavetype){
           case "1":

        $date1 = new \DateTime($model->startDate);
        $date2 = new \DateTime($model->endDate);
        $end = $date2->format('Y-m-d');
        $interval = new \DateInterval('P1D');
        $date2 -> add($interval);
        $period = new \DatePeriod($date1, $interval, $date2);

        foreach($period as $date){
            $allDates[] = [
                'date'=>$date->format('Y-m-d'),
                'dayNo'=>$date->format('N'),
            ];
        }
        $holidays = Publicholiday::find()
        ->select('date')
        ->where(['between', 'date', $date1->format('Y-m-d'), $end])
        ->indexBy('date')
        ->column();

        $workDay = 0;

        foreach($allDates as $value){
            $isWeekOff = $value['dayNo'] == 6 || $value ['dayNo'] == 7;

            if(!$isWeekOff && !isset($holidays [$value['date']])){
                $workDay++;
            }
        }
            $model->no_of_days = $workDay;
            $model->save();

            $annualleave = Annualleave::find()
            ->select('leaveBalance')
            ->where(['staffNo'=>$model1->staffNo])
            ->one();

            $annualleave = $annualleave - $workDay;
            $model1->leaveBalance = $annualleave;
            $model1->save();


break; ......
```

Supposed the result of `leaveBalance` will be 23.5. But with that code, the system creates new data like below:

[image]

Comment: Still chances that it is unclear to others. Add create action code of leave application.

Comment: thank you sir, already edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `$model1` new Instance for AnnualLeave. You just need to modify existing AnnualLeave.

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Leaveapplication();
    //$model1 = new Annualleave();
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    $annualleave = Annualleave::find()
        ->where(['staffNo' => $model->staffNo])
        ->one();

    $annualleave->leaveBalance = $annualleave->leaveBalance - $workDay;
    $annualleave->save();
    .
    .
```

Comment: its work sir! thank you so much. cant describe with the words how appreciate i am to you.